# CheckBox widget in the top right corner of an image

Tags: android, image, checkbox, picasso, clickable

Currently I am downloading 2 images per row via Picasso. I'd want to add a CheckBox in the top right corner of each of them. How should the checkbox be defined? Here is the layout so far:

```
<!--Row1-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            style="@style/singleImage"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            style="@style/singleImage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the style:

```
<style name="singleImage">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
</style>
```

Comment: First you add 2 CheckBox on your layout, then use RelativeLayout to grouping (ImageView_1 and CheckBox_1) & (ImageView_2 and CheckBox_2)

Comment: Okey, but how to align them and make them appear over the images? Following your advice, they simply substituted the images.

Comment: `<RelativeLayout
       ... >

        <ImageView
           ... />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="" />
    </RelativeLayout>`

Comment: Once I add RelativeLayout withing the LinearLayout, the image cannot be downloaded from the server and is not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment its mean like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Oh, now I understood! Thank a lot, it's great!